# Piechart with mschart (r package)

Tags: r, mschart, officer

With the package [mschart](https://ardata-fr.github.io/mschart/reference/index.html), it is possible to create several kinds of charts, according to the official documentation

- ms_areachart()
- ms_barchart()
- ms_linechart()
- ms_scatterchart()

However, **piechart** is not one of them. Is it possible to modify of them to obtain a piechart?

Comment: Not according to their documention (not that piecharts are a good way of visualizing usually).

Comment: Why don't you use https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html? (and as deschen wrote, Piecharts are kind of oufdated, would consider to use other ways of visualisation)

Comment: The OP wants MS-friendly output.  Exporting as SVG might work to give you something that can be embedded in MS documents and editable ...

Comment: I don't think so. [Someone requested this a while ago](https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/issues/55). It's hard to prove a negative, but I suspect you're out of luck.